# Combine selector or retrieve action parameter in effect pipeline

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

Given the following action:

```
export const UpsertChartMember = createAction(ClubDetailActionTypes.UPSERT_CHART_MEMBER, props<{ clubId: number, member: IChartMember}>());
```

I'd like to retrieve the `clubId` action parameter in the `map` operator to dispatch another action:

```
@Effect({ dispatch: false })
  upsertChartMember = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(UpsertChartMember),
    mergeMap(action => {
      const member = action.member;
      return this.chartMemberDataService.update(member);
    }),
    map(member => {
      this.messageService.success(this.constService.SAVE_SUCCESS);
      this.clubDetailStore.dispatch(UpsertChartMemberSuccess({ member: member }));

      // retrieve action.clubId here?! O_o?
      // TODO: dispatch here another action based upon action clubId

    }),
    catchError((error) => {
      this.messageService.error(this.constService.SAVE_FAILURE);
      this.clubDetailStore.dispatch(UpsertClubChartFailure({ err: error }));
      return throwError(error);
    }),
  );
```

as alternative I have already in the feature store module the `clubId` accessible by a dedicated selector:

```
export const getCurrentClub$ = createSelector(getclubDetailState$, (state: ClubDetailState) => state.form);
```

but I don't understand how to combine the selector and the result of ajax call in my effect...

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `switchMap` to grab it from the store using the selector you already have and a `combineLatest` to keep pass the `member` info forward along with the `club` grabbed from the store:

```js
@Effect({ dispatch: false })
  upsertChartMember = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(UpsertChartMember),
    mergeMap(action => {
      const member = action.member;
      return this.chartMemberDataService.update(member);
    }),
    switchMap(member => combineLatest([
      of(member),
      this.store.pipe(select(getCurrentClub$)),
    ])),
    map(([member,club]) => {
      this.messageService.success(this.constService.SAVE_SUCCESS);
      this.clubDetailStore.dispatch(UpsertChartMemberSuccess({ member: member }));

      // now you have your club to do whatever you want to
      console.log({club});

    }),
    catchError((error) => {
      this.messageService.error(this.constService.SAVE_FAILURE);
      this.clubDetailStore.dispatch(UpsertClubChartFailure({ err: error }));
      return throwError(error);
    }),
  );
```

BTW, the code above can return both the actions directly. By using `switchMap`. Instead of map, you can use another chain:

```js
@Effect()
  upsertChartMember = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(UpsertChartMember),
    mergeMap(action => {
      const member = action.member;
      return this.chartMemberDataService.update(member);
    }),
    switchMap(member => combineLatest([
      of(member),
      this.store.pipe(select(getCurrentClub$)),
    ])),
    switchMap(([member, club]) => {
      this.messageService.success(this.constService.SAVE_SUCCESS);  
      return [
        UpsertChartMemberSuccess({ member: member }),
        PutYourOtherActionHere({club...})
      ];
    }),
    catchError((error) => {
      this.messageService.error(this.constService.SAVE_FAILURE);
      this.clubDetailStore.dispatch(UpsertClubChartFailure({ err: error }));
      return throwError(error);
    }),
  );
```

**[Edited by the question author]:** Or, by keeping most of your code right as it is:

```js
@Effect({ dispatch: false })
  upsertChartMember: any = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(UpsertChartMember),
    mergeMap(action => {
      const member = action.member;
      let obs: Observable<IChartMember>;
      if (member.id > 0) {
        obs = this.chartMemberDataService.update(member);
      } else {
        obs = this.chartMemberDataService.add(member);
      }
      return combineLatest(of(action), obs);
    }),
    map((args) => {
      this.messageService.success(this.constService.SAVE_SUCCESS);
      this.clubDetailStore.dispatch(UpsertChartMemberSuccess({ member: args[1] }));
      this.clubDetailStore.dispatch(GetClubOrganizationCharts({clubId: args[0].clubId}));
    }),
    catchError((error) => {
      this.messageService.error(this.constService.SAVE_FAILURE);
      this.clubDetailStore.dispatch(UpsertClubChartFailure({ err: error }));
      return throwError(error);
    }),
  );
```

Comment: I've noticed just now you're not using the action and effect creators.

Comment: you are rigth, but doesn't matter right now, thanks a lot